# how to fix encoding issue in the API call

Tags: c#, web-services, encoding, utf-8, url-encoding

I m making calls to a third party API over HTTP and passing a string in the parameters. This string is UTF-8 URL encoded. My API client is written in asp.net C# where as the API host is probably written in Java. When I have characters like parenthesis/brackets () in the string parameter, UTF-8 encoder does not encode them whereas the API host encodes them in %28 and %29 and I get incorrect response. Any suggestions how to fix this encoding problem?

(API documentation specify to use UTF-8 encoding and recommends to refer this document http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are some little known Uri methods:[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Uri_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Uri.EscapeString and Uri.EscapeDataString may fit the bill. unfortunately there is no MSDN documentation on what characters they will encode , you will just have to experiment.

Comment: thanks but none of these two methods encode brackets

Comment: try this:      Console.WriteLine(System.Uri.EscapeDataString("()"));